# How to use table variable in a NOT IN sql statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use the table variable @notified in a NOT IN where clause like this....

```
DECLARE @notified TABLE (DMT_ID INT)

INSERT INTO @notified
    SELECT [DMT_ID] 
    FROM [dbo].[PU_Transaction] 
    WHERE [PU_TransactionStatus] = 3

SELECT * from @notified 

SELECT [NRO_TRANSACCION] 
FROM [dbo].[TRANSACCION] 
WHERE [NRO_TRANSACCION] NOT in (@notified)
```

But I am getting this error in the last SELECT

> Must declare the scalar variable "@notified".

What is wrong ? How can this be solved.

Comment: You need to select a column from @notified in the in clause.

Comment: `... NOT IN (SELECT DMT_ID FROM @notified)...`

Comment: @ZLK that is it, is so obivous now. Thanks, If you post it as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
SELECT [NRO_TRANSACCION] 
FROM [dbo].[TRANSACCION] 
WHERE [NRO_TRANSACCION] NOT IN (SELECT DMT_ID FROM @notified)
```

You need to put a `SELECT` statement in the `NOT IN` clause - not just a table variable name...

Answer (score 1):

select x from y where x not in (select x from z)

You should have two selects to use a not in.

Comment: I think you want:
    SELECT [NRO_TRANSACCION] FROM [dbo].[TRANSACCION] WHERE [NRO_TRANSACCION] not in (select [NRO_TRANSACCION] from [DMT_ID INT])